# How to give child process control of the terminal, in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, terminal, child-process

I have a Node app that I run from the terminal (`node myapp.js`).
This app spawns a child node process (via `child_process.fork`).

After that happens, I want to exit the parent process, and give the child process control of the terminal. Right now, when I exit the parent, the child process simply runs in the background, and the terminal goes back to bash. How can I give the terminal to the child process, so it doesn't go back to bash?

Comment: If you want to fork the child process, then immediately die as the parent and have the child take over, my question is: why fork a new process at all?

Comment: It would be convenient to be able to separate my processes by functionality, instead of lumping them all into one process. It would allow for increased modularity.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `child_process.spawn` as well as `options.detached` in the node.js docs. Something like this could be what you are looking for:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const child = spawn(process.argv[0], ['child_program.js'], {
  detached: true,
  stdio: ['ignore']
});

child.unref(); //causes the parent's event loop to not include the child in its reference count, allowing the parent to exit independently of the child, unless there is an established IPC channel between the child and parent.
```

Node provides child_process module which has following three major ways to create child process.

- exec - child_process.exec method runs a command in a shell/console and buffers the output.
- spawn - child_process.spawn launches a new process with a given command
- fork - The child_process.fork method is a special case of the spawn() to create child processes.